# Delete duplicate records in a pandas dataframe, but keep one based on alphabetical order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I cross-joined a query and returned it as a DataFrame in Python. Now I have a dataframe df that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Peter', 'Tom',1], ['Sam', 'Ed',2], ['Tom', 'Peter',1], ['Ed', 'Sam',2]], columns=["Person 1", "Person 2", "Value"])


df 
   Person1 Person2 Value
0   Peter   Tom    1
1   Sam     Ed     2
2   Tom     Peter  1
3   Ed      Sam    2
```

However, I need to remove the duplicates and keep only record for each pair. I want to keep the pair based on whose name is first in the alphabet, and have my final dataframe look like this:

```
df_final

   Person1  Person2 Value
0   Ed      Sam      2
1   Peter   Tom      1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort across columns via [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df_sorted = np.hstack((np.sort(df.iloc[:, :-1].values, axis=1),
                       df['Value'].values[:, None]))

res = pd.DataFrame(df_sorted, columns=df.columns)\
        .drop_duplicates()

print(res)

  Person 1 Person 2 Value
0    Peter      Tom     1
1       Ed      Sam     2
```

Comment: how will it know which one to drop ? I'm not sure i understand what the code is doing

Comment: `np.sort` along `axis=1` sorts each row independently. `drop_duplicates` by default across all columns, i.e. if all values in a row match a previous row, the row is dropped. The docs I've linked to in the answer are very useful if you wish to understand these 2 methods.

Comment: Sorry that I missed a column, but my dataframe has the third column equal to value and the error says 'TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()'. How can i fix that ?

Comment: @toceto, Then just sort the first 2 columns and stack the 3rd.. have updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) on data sorted using [`np.sort`](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=np.sort&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), and use the mask to remove duplicates. This should be simpler.

```
# Sort columns and generate a duplicate mask.
m = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.iloc[:, :2])).duplicated()
print(m) 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool

df = df[~m]  # Use mask to drop duplicate rows.
print(df) 
  Person 1 Person 2  Value
0    Peter      Tom      1
1      Sam       Ed      2
```

Also note that the order of the original data is preserved.

Comment: I need Ed to be person 1, and Sam to be Person 2 because Ed comes first in alphabetical order. That's why I chose jpp's answer as correct, but thank you for your help.